# When doing role based routing in react, is use of switch statement and showing different component based on role a security issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have the following code, its simple and does the job. But is there security issues with this? This is my first time doing role based authorization so trying to understand what I can do better.

```js
<Route path={"/"} component={RootPage}></Route>

export default const RootPage({role}) => {
    switch(role) {
        case USER: return <MainPageUser />
        case ADMIN: return <AdminPage />
        default: return <MainPage />
    }
}
```

Comment: is it always loading Mainpage?. where u got `{role}` value

Comment: @sarvonks sorry that will be passed in as prop in the route component

Comment: are you using `react-router-dom` ?

Comment: @Vencovsky yes i am

Comment: If the `role` value is stored in something like your browser's localStorage, users could potentially edit their localStorage to set their role to `ADMIN` and they'd be redirected to the admin page. Ideally you'd have some kind of server side check to check authorization every time you navigate to a page.

Comment: always loading single component or different  component

Comment: @sarvonks in my route it will always be "rootpage" component. So one in this case. Then the rootpage will do the switch and spit out the appropriate page for the user

Comment: @nbokmans roles are stored in dynamodb, so nothing will exist in localstorage or any client side storage. does that help?

Comment: got it man in root page <MainPageUser /> or return <AdminPage /> or  <MainPage /> which one loading

Comment: @sarvonks depends on which role is associated with the user, i will be getting the role from dynamodb where i am storing the roles there

Comment: add console.log(role) above switch case.share

Comment: @sarvonks i haven't implemented that far yet, but logically i will be getting roles from dynamodb and passing it on when user logs in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options you can choose from, all of them are (almost) just as (un)safe as the other. It's javascript, if someone wants to, then can change it as it's client side.

You can do the switch as you are doing, or something like:

```
{role==="admin" && <AdminStuff />} // the component only gets rendered if the first part is true
{role==="user"  && <UserStuff />}  // so in this case it's one or the other.
```

You can also create a component thats called a voter:

```
function RoleVoter({grantedRole, requiredRole, children){
    render(){
        return grantedRole===requiredRole ? children : null;
    }
}
// Example:
<RoleVoter grantedRole={role} requiredRole={ADMIN}> <AdminStuff/> </RoleVoter>
```

Each varies in complexity and usability, they all have their benefits/drawback. The switch is usefull if "only one case may match". The `&&` method is good for quick coding, but will result in hardcoding very fast, hard to maintain. The RoleVoter aproach is more complex and might be overkill, but you can now throw every role in there you want. And expand it to understand  multiple roles (eg ADMIN and VIEW_ORDERS if you want that kind of level of security).

---

All of these are about as safe as the other. It's Javascript, at happens clientside, nothing you can do about that. What is more important, is that you pick a solution which is easy to implement/understand by the developers. The reason for that is that the easier security becomes to implement, the more often you will implement it.

**Then where lies the real security?** Easy: Serverside. Imagine you hack some javascript and you get it to show you an admin page, but the server never gave it the actual content. Pretty useless. You also create the security checks serverside based on the current user.

A somewhat standard method is that you make voters (small functions) that each test two things:

- Can the user add/view/edit/delete this type of item (in general)? E.g. does the user have EDIT_USER permission when trying to edit a user? Or a VIEW_ORDER when trying to view an order?
- Can the user add/view/edit/delete *this specific item*? E.g. if you can only change an order when it's your own, is it actually yours?

Comment: I should have mentioned i intend to make the check server side and pass that to the front end. So in dynamodb we are going to keep a list of users and roles associated with each user. Then when user needs to access admin page for example, I would hit dynamodb to check the role of the authenticated user then flow it back to the front end. Where I would use something like rolevoter to show the appropriate component. Does that make sense?

Comment: It doesnt really matter that much what you do frontend. As long as no secure data makes it to the front and, nothing bad is going on

Comment: For high level view: If all I do when user logs in, is query dynamodb to see what role belongs to user, then pass that back --lets say in this case role name is "admin"- Role comes back to front end as "admin", then roleVoter picks it up and shows the appropriate admin page. Can't the front end javascript be changed still? Role voter is determining what component to render based on what prop is passed in still regardless of if the prop is coming from server side or client side as in initial example. Or am I confusing this?

Comment: Yeah, someone can change it. You "just" open your browsers console and fiddle around with stuff and see what happens. But I can never change my role server side. I could change my javascript value from "user" to "admin", but that doesn't make me on serverside. So someone might see the admin page, but empty as the server never serves the content.

Comment: You should flip your logic: The user can see **all** pages, all routes, all script, everything clientside, always. So also the admin page. But, the server never provides the actual content, and as we're kind folks, we hide the empty admin pages from the user.

Comment: Oh i think i get it...you can't do any CRUD methods correct? I can go ahead and play with the view, but if i want to make any changes its going to have to go through the server! if so then perfect, i shall be marking this answer the right one

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Even if I get to an admin page and manage to guess to proper data to set via the API, the server is gonna "That's great and all that you've changed your role, but I (the server) didnt so im not gonna process it.